# Showing that a $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism of a field $E$ fixes $i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $E = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}, i)$ and that we have an automorphism of $E$, say $\theta: E\rightarrow E$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\theta(2^{1/4}) = i 2^{1/4}$. I am trying to show that $\theta(i) = i$.

I can only show that $\theta(i) = \pm i$, since $\theta(i)^2 = \theta(i^2) = \theta(-1) = -1$ so $\theta(i) = \pm i$.

However, is there anyway to show that $\theta(i) = i$?

Comment: It's not true: $E$ is the splitting field of $x^4-2$, hence a Galois extension, and $[E:\mathbb Q]=8$, so the Galois group has eight elements.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is a subfield of $E$, so any $\theta \in \mathrm{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q}(i))$ fixes $i$. This group is a subgroup of $G=\mathrm{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ and extend $\theta$ to get an automorphism that fixes $i$ and that sends the root $2^{1/4}$ to the other root $i2^{1/4}$ (the group  $G$ is transitive because the polynomial is irreducible).